# Translate "héhé" to English

Tags: translation, french, onomatopoeia

I know that's a really weird question but really interesting I think.

In French, we say **héhé** when we're **kindly** (like a friend would do) making fun of someone or something. We could also replace it by a ❤ emoticon like to tell to the person that we said it [what we said just before] **kindly**.

Comment: Simply removing the diacritical marks would make it perfectly normal in English.  *Hehe* works just fine.  Heart signs and other such emoticons work in most Western cultures, if not most cultures everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is as simple as this

> hehe

Have a look at [this](http://www.interglot.com/dictionary/fr/en/search?q=h%C3%A9h%C3%A9&l=fr%7Ces).

[hehe emoticon](http://www.sherv.net/hehe-emoticon-301.html)